# Designing a Switch to Protect ADC from 5V Signal

Tags: gpio, adc

I have a question regarding the implementation of a switch between an ADC and a 5V tolerant GPIO pad, as described in the STM32 manual. Here are the relevant images for reference:

[image]
[image]

In my design, I would like to implement a switch between the ADC and the pad, as shown in the following image:
[image]

However, I am unsure about how to design this switch to protect the ADC from the 5V signal. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or recommendations you may have regarding this matter.

Comment: Fred Nguyen - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that if a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). Therefore please [edit] your question to include the original source links for those images (and please remember it's your responsibility to do that in future). Thanks. (Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules.)